# How to put functions in different files in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have a couple of functions in the NSIS installer. I want to keep them neatly in separate files.

For example, the main `section` is in the files `installer.nsi` and now I want to put a function to compare versions in a separate file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own include files (just a normal text file with the .nsh extension):

**VersionCompare.nsh**:

```
Function MyVersionCompare
# ...
FunctionEnd
```

**Installer.nsi**:

```
Name "MyInstaller"
OutFile "MyInstaller.exe"

!include "VersionCompare.nsh"

Section
Call MyVersionCompare 
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks, it works if the `VersionCompare.nsh` and `Installer.nsi` are in the same directory. But if the put the `VersionCompare.nsh` in a folder which is in the directory where `Installer.nsi`is present then I get an error `!include: could not find: "InstallerFiles.nsh/VersionCompare.nsh"`

Comment: !include supports relative paths.